# C# Parse SSIS Column from SSIS Package

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm successfully parsing the cachedname of a column from an input collection collection as shown here:

```
                    DtsWrapper.MainPipe m = (DtsWrapper.MainPipe)TH.InnerObject;
                    DtsWrapper.IDTSComponentMetaDataCollection100 mdc = m.ComponentMetaDataCollection;

                    foreach (DtsWrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100 md in mdc)
                    {
                        IDTSInput100 input = md.InputCollection[0];
                        foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 column in input.InputColumnCollection)
                        {
                            treeView1.Nodes["Executables"].Nodes[TH.Name].Nodes[md.Name].Nodes.Add(column.Name, column.Name);
                        }
                    }
```

I can't figure out how to parse externalMetadataColumnId and lineageid. Here is the package xml. Any suggestions?

```
           <inputColumns>
                <inputColumn
                  refId="Package\Data Flow Task\Dynamics CRM Destination.Inputs[Input].Columns[guid]"
                  cachedDataType="guid"
                  cachedName="guid"
                  externalMetadataColumnId="Package\Data Flow Task\Dynamics CRM Destination.Inputs[Input].ExternalColumns[accountid]"
                  lineageId="Package\Data Flow Task\OLE DB Source.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[guid]" />
                <inputColumn
                  refId="Package\Data Flow Task\Dynamics CRM Destination.Inputs[Input].Columns[cr031_accountseed]"
                  cachedDataType="wstr"
                  cachedLength="20"
                  cachedName="cr031_accountseed"
                  externalMetadataColumnId="Package\Data Flow Task\Dynamics CRM Destination.Inputs[Input].ExternalColumns[xxc_account_alt_id]"
                  lineageId="Package\Data Flow Task\OLE DB Source.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[cr031_accountseed]" />
              </inputColumns>
```

Thanks

Comment: So the question is where in the object model can one access those properties?

Comment: Yes. CM.Name gets me the cachedName but how do I access externalMetadataColumnId  and lineageid properties?

Comment: No idea, but just wanted to verify what you were after. I _thought_ that with the change to 2012 vs 2008/2005 way of doing things, the lineage/column id didn't matter as those were regenerated or something like that. Best of luck as the documentation for working with the object model is sparse at best

Comment: do you have <inputColumns>...</inputColumns> in a string already?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this in a string already this is pretty simple:

```
       <inputColumns>
            <inputColumn
              refId="Package\Data Flow Task\Dynamics CRM Destination.Inputs[Input].Columns[guid]"
              cachedDataType="guid"
              cachedName="guid"
              externalMetadataColumnId="Package\Data Flow Task\Dynamics CRM Destination.Inputs[Input].ExternalColumns[accountid]"
              lineageId="Package\Data Flow Task\OLE DB Source.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[guid]" />
            <inputColumn
              refId="Package\Data Flow Task\Dynamics CRM Destination.Inputs[Input].Columns[cr031_accountseed]"
              cachedDataType="wstr"
              cachedLength="20"
              cachedName="cr031_accountseed"
              externalMetadataColumnId="Package\Data Flow Task\Dynamics CRM Destination.Inputs[Input].ExternalColumns[xxc_account_alt_id]"
              lineageId="Package\Data Flow Task\OLE DB Source.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[cr031_accountseed]" />
          </inputColumns>
```

Build a class to load the data into an object:

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="inputColumn")]
    public class InputColumn {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="refId")]
        public string RefId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="cachedDataType")]
        public string CachedDataType { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="cachedName")]
        public string CachedName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="externalMetadataColumnId")]
        public string ExternalMetadataColumnId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="lineageId")]
        public string LineageId { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="cachedLength")]
        public string CachedLength { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="inputColumns")]
    public class InputColumns {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="inputColumn")]
        public List<InputColumn> InputColumn { get; set; }
    }
```

And then in your code use this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InputColumns));
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader([your column]))
{
    InputColumns xml= (InputColumns )(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
    [now you can use xml object to get whatever you want]
    //this is you most likely use case
    foreach(var col in xml.inputColumn)
    {....}
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to retrieve using the IDTSInputColumn100 object. I'll try the xml strategy if there isn't a respond on how to achieve it using IDTSInputColumn100 .